# How can i solved in app purchase SKProductsResponse invaild ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

Hey guys i am frustrated to retrieve a product from iTunesConnect but it always return invalid ID. I fulfill all requirements but not getting any response from it. I followed these steps and my answer is Yes..
.Please give me some solution to solve this problem. Thanks in advance..

```
1.Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
2.Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?
3.Have you submitted (and optionally rejected) your application binary?
4.Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
5.Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?
6.Have you configured your project to code sign using this new provisioning profile?
7.Are you building for iPhone OS 3.0 or above?
8.Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest? Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect?
9.Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect? (via Mark) Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling? (via Hector, S3B, Alex O, Joe, and Alberto)
```

Code:

```
-(void)fetchAvailableProducts{
    NSSet *productSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.magazineapp.books",nil];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                       initWithProductIdentifiers:productSet];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}
- (void)purchaseMyProduct:(SKProduct*)product{
    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
      //  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                  @"Purchases are disabled in your device" message:nil delegate:
                                  self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
-(IBAction)purchase:(id)sender{
    [self purchaseMyProduct:[validProducts objectAtIndex:0]];
}

#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"Purchasing");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                     isEqualToString:kMySubscriptionFeature]) {
                    NSLog(@"Purchased ");
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                              @"Purchase is completed succesfully" message:nil delegate:
                                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alertView show];
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    NSUInteger count = [response.products count];
    if (count>0) {
        validProducts = response.products;
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([validProduct.productIdentifier
             isEqualToString:kMySubscriptionFeature]) {
            DLog(@"vaild product");
        }
    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                            message:@"No products to purchase"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];
    }    
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
  }
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `fetchAvailableProducts` method and have you enabled the `In App Purchases` in your project target's capabilities?

Comment: yes alex sir , i enable in app purchase in project target's capabilities and i calling fetchAvailableProducts in viewDidAppear method

Comment: Please share the error details that you receive when you try to fetch the products.

Comment: yea Adeel Miraj sir, Printing description of response->_internal->_invalidIdentifiers:
<__NSCFArray 0x7a095a20>(
com.magazineapp.books
)

Comment: the `invalidIdentifier` suggests that the product identifiers that you are providing in your `fetchAvailableProducts` method does not match with the product identifier(s) that you have registered on iTunesconnect. I think you are providing your bundle identifier instead of the product identifier. Please check.

Comment: no I already check my product id that is com.magazineapp.books and i already use to request with bundle id or with product id and product id append with bundle identifier....but never get any response..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125591/discussion-between-adeel-miraj-and-yatish-agrawal).

Comment: yes why not are you on skype my skype id is yatishagrawalnanu